# how to select link in title with jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-plugins

I have a div that has a title in it (below). Using JQuery how do I select the link in the title?

```
<div href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='<?php echo "admin/".$item['img'] ?>'
 width='70' height='70' /><a  style='float:left;margin:19px auto;' class='button 
 topmenu'>send</a>
```

How can I get the link in this title with jquery like this:

```
$(".tooltip[title][a]").click(function()...
```

How can I select link in the title?

Comment: `$(".tooltip[title] a").click(`... That selects the a tags within the item with class tooltip (which also has a title).

Comment: This is not legal, why are you trying to put an `img` into a `title` attribute?

Comment: yee, like this the only ilegal thing! `href` on a div? something is wrong here...

Comment: You want the img src set in div title?

Comment: I presume the extra attributes may be used by the tooltip addin they have (and unknown attributes are guaranteed to be ignored by the browser).

Comment: because i use a plugin http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/

Comment: for show tooltips i can only use title ..

Comment: Seriously, your plugin needs to have an attribute href set on a DIV??? This is certainly not related to your issue but looks so bad

Comment: He doesn't need href in the div i think it was a copy paste from one of the documents made a demo here with tooltipster http://jsfiddle.net/JD8sA/3/

Comment: I am going to go out on a limb here and say... huh? Which link do you want? The src value in the title image src, or the anchor (which I have assumed)?

Comment: this is really the most "srange" code i have every seen before. <href> for dv, image in title, you could even add 2 or more "ID" properites for this combination :D :)  to solve your problem you need at first to have a right structure

Answer (score 0):

As I was saying, the selector has a minor issue:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JD8sA/1/

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $(".tooltip[title] a").click(function(){
        alert("Clicked!")

        // "this" is the anchor DOM element - the following converts it to a JQuery object
        var  $link = $(this);

        // the URL is in the href attribute on the anchor/link
        var href = $link.attr('href');
    });
});
```

This selector says "I want any anchor inside a class of tooltip that has a title".

Your previous selector was saying "I want a class named tooltip that also has a title and also has an attribute called a".

Comment: when i use $(".tooltip[title]").click(function(){
        alert("Clicked!")
it worked !!! but when click in link it doesnt work

Comment: The example JSFiddle works fine for me. Can you update the JSFiddle to show your current "non-working" code and any additional styling in the css panel?

Comment: please go to my sample

Comment: Sample works in IE 10... No tooltip at all in Chrome. What are you expecting to happen when you click "send"? Your anchor/link has no `href` so will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.tooltip a').click(function{
  window.location = $(this).parent('.tooltip').attr('title');
});
```

oh damn...it's not the parent :(

Comment: The wording was a little ambiguous, but I think they just wanted the anchor link inside their tooltip. The use of the term title is confusing as they have the title attribute on the div. If it worked this would try to change the browser url to an image tag rather than the address in the img tag (which you may have meant).